# timestamp of newly created file is in the future

Tags: files, timestamps

On my machine at work I experience weird timestamps of files. This is bothering me, because it messes with `make`.

To reproduce the issue, this suffices:

```
$ touch foo
$ stat -c %y foo
2014-01-31 16:38:51.000000000 +0100
$ date
Fr 31. Jan 16:14:59 CET 2014
```

As you can see, the file, although just created, has a timestamp that is roughly 24 minutes in the future. To be precise, it is fairly stable at 24 minutes and 8 seconds, which is 1448 seconds, to me a seemingly arbitrary number.

The same holds for directories freshly created with `mkdir` or simply any kind of file saving / creating stuff.

Our administrator is fairly unresponsive and didn't gave root permissions either. What might be the cause of this issue and how to deal with it, if possible without root?

Comment: According to a man page it's possible to pass a custom date/timestamp to the `touch` command. Don't you have any aliases by any chance, which can affect touch?

Comment: @UVV Negative. No alias. This affects all types of file creation, not just touch. For example saving a document with gedit or similar results in the same situation.

Comment: Could that be your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497761/touching-a-file-sets-it-modified-in-the-future ?

Comment: @UVV it _might_ be. I'd need to check with my administrator but that usually takes some weeks. Any way to test that myself?

Comment: Is the filesystem local or remote?  If it is remote, likely the time on the remote machine is wrong and ahead of your clock.  Convince your admin to use NTP or something to keep the clocks in sync.

Comment: @stefan just check the output of `mount` command and compare the dir where you are.

Comment: Probably the easiest way to find out what filesystem you're on is `df .`, which reports the filesystem of the current directory (as well as how much free space it has).

Comment: @UVV thanks. It seems like you are right and this is a NFS.

Comment: Then to avoid that your should follow casey's advise and use NTP.

Comment: @UVV, you should post that as an answer so he can accept it.  We can't mark it as duplicate because the other question is on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you are on remote file system and the timestamp is generated there. To confirm that you can use either `mount` command and check your current directory or `df .`. It's advisable to use NTP to avoid that situation.